# extract a corrupt or delete table

Tags: sql-server, recovery

What is the correct way and what is the steps to just recover and restore one big table from sqlserver 2019 backup in production server in an emergency situation?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the correct way and what is the steps to just recover and restore one big table from sqlserver 2019 backup

You don't. It's not possible with native SQL Server database backups. You can restore the entire backup to a separate database and then copy the single table back into its original database.

You can use an alternative backup solution through 3rd party tools that do offer object level recovery, if that's important to you. Some of these tools are:

1. [RedGate SQL Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/)
2. [Quest LiteSpeed](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/)
3. [Idera SQL Safe](http://www.idera.com/SQL-Server/sql-safe-backup/)